# Find Inactive Canvas Panel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I need to find a inactive panel. I can't use GameObject.Find and serializedfield because after game restart the serialized variable linked to inactive panel gets destroyed cause of singleton class I'm using. What other ways could I use?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll.html), it returns all the objects in assets and scene.

If the parent of this panel is actived, you can also use `GameObject.Find` and `Transform.Find` to find it.

Comment: I use your second option

Answer (score 0):

you could assign a tag to the panel and use `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(string tag)` to find it, if you have a lot of panels in your scene, and you just want the inactive one you can loop through the GameObjects found by the `FindGameObjectsWithTag(string tag)` function and check which ones are inactive.